# XmlDocument - xpath returns nothing

Tags: xpath, .net-6.0, xmldocument

I'm trying to read this science.org feed: https://www.science.org/rss/news_current.xml

with this simple code:

```
using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
var response = httpClient.Send(request);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(content);
var items = xmlDoc.DocumentElement?.SelectNodes("//item");
if (items != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{url}: items={items.Count}");
}
```

but I get 0 items...
(the 'content' variable is good and contains the right xml data)

It works for other RSS feeds.

any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the root element includes this default namespace declaration: `xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"`, which means that the names of elements within the document are qualified by that namespace URI, unless they have an explicit namespace prefix. Your `item` elements have no prefix, which means they do belong to that RSS namespace.

So instead of querying for elements named `item`, you will need to include a namespace prefix in your query, e.g. `//rss:item`, and of course to allow that prefix to make sense to the SelectNodes method, you'll need to bind the `rss` prefix to the namespace URI `http://purl.org/rss/1.0/`. See the documentation for [SelectNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmlnode-selectnodes(system-string-system-xml-xmlnamespacemanager)) for information about how to handle the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But if I want to read another feed, like http://feeds.hanselman.com/scotthanselman, I can't without knowing which namespace to use? (because I just want the <item> tags, but if they are in different namespaces...)

Comment: The document in your question is an RSS 1.0 feed, while the feed at http://feeds.hanselman.com/scotthanselman is an RSS 2.0 feed (in which the `item` element is not namespaced). If you want to be able to support both syndication formats with a single XPath expression, you could use `//rss:item | //item` which would search for elements with either name.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XPath 2 and do e.g.

```
using System.Xml;
using Wmhelp.XPath2;

var doc = new XmlDocument(new NameTable());
doc.Load(@"https://www.science.org/rss/news_current.xml");

var xmlNamespaceMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

xmlNamespaceMgr.AddNamespace("", "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/");

var items = doc.XPath2SelectNodes("//item", xmlNamespaceMgr);

Console.WriteLine(items.Count);
```

by using the NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2.